# estimating lambda for a exponential distribution using method of MLE

Tags: r, mle

I am attempting to estimate lambda using the method of maximum likelihood estimation.

Here is the code I am using:

```
set.seed(0)
x=rexp(100,10)
plot(x)
fn <- function(lambda){
   length(x)*log(lambda)-lambda*sum(x)
 }
plot(fn)
optim(lambda, fn)
```

> Error in optim(lambda, fn) : object 'lambda' not found nlm(fn, lambda)
>   Error in nlm(fn, lambda) : object 'lambda' not found

Clearly my issue is with the error I am not sure how to fix it.
can anyone tell me how to fix this so that i can get the estimation or perhaps recommend a better method?

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing. So this is a case for the `optimize` function

```
# Build Data
set.seed(0)
x=rexp(100,10)
```

Modifying the equation for log-likelihood slightly we have (still numerically equivalent):

```
log_like_lambda <- function(lambda, x){
  length(x) * log(lambda) - lambda*length(x)*mean(x)
}
```

We can then use our optimize function to find the maximum.

```
optimize(f = log_like_lambda, x, interval = c(1,15), maximum = TRUE)
```

Which outputs our maximum as expected from the fake data

```
$maximum
[1] 9.688527

$objective
[1] 127.0944
```

Aside:

Note that it is also helpful to plot the log-likelihood to make sure you are optimizing what you think you are optimizing:

```
log_like <- log_like_lambda(1:50)
plot(log_like)
```

[image: log-like-exp-func]

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues here:

1. The first argument should be a numeric vector (of length 1 in this case)
2. `optim()` *minimizes*, so you either need `control=list(fnscale=-1))` or to redefine your function as the negative log-likelihood

```
optim(1,fn,control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

works, although it gives a warning suggesting that you should use `method="Brent"`.

You might want to consider the `fitdistr()` function in the `MASS` package (for MLE fits to a variety of distributions), or the `mle2()` function in the `bbmle` package (for general MLE, including this case, e.g. `mle2(x ~ dpois(lambda), data=data.frame(x), start=list(lambda=1))`